# Keyboard is not working, can't type the letter s

Tags: windows, keyboard, key-binding

Hello everyone and happy Thanksgiving eve.

I am having keyboard trouble. I can't type the letter <kbd>s</kbd> on my keyboard. I am using a laptop, but I have tried using an external keyboard too, and I get the same result.

Comment: Have you tried typing the letter 's' using the virtual keyboard? and what is the results if so?

Comment: how do i do thi_

Comment: You can access the On-Screen keyboard from windows Start button > All Programs > Accessories > Ease of Access > On-Screen Keyboard. This is on windows 7 machine. What is the operating system you use?

Comment: I am running Windowz. I can't find that. :( I need to get thiz fixed or I will get in trouble

Comment: If it is on Windows vista and later version, you can open it just by typing "On-Screen Keyboard" in the Start > Search Programs and Files box. If it is on Windows XP then, Start button > All Programs > Accessories > Accessibility > On-Screen Keyboard to open On-Screen Keyboard

Comment: I went to ztart > all programz> accezzoriez > accezzibility but don't zee "On zcreen keyboard" there

Comment: What happens when you type "S" - nothing? Or some other letter appears? Have you tried doing a Repair to your Windows installation? Try the following - press the alt-key and then type 0 1 1 5 on your numeric keypad and then release the alt-key - "s" should appear - does it?

Comment: I don't know how to repair.  My laptop doez not have that key. When I prezz the key nothing happenz

Comment: Why the hell waz my queztion marked az unclear? How can I fix the problem now? Nobody helped me!!

Comment: You could try to fix the s key on your keyboard layout using a tool from Microsoft called [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx). In order to install this program you also need to have another Microsoft program called Microsoft .NET Framework v2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Download a Linux live DVD like Ubuntu or Mint.

Boot from the DVD and try your keyboard.

If the "s" key does not work, then it is a hardware problem.

Buy a new laptop on Friday.

If the key works, then reinstall Windowz

Comment: I don't have a dvd burner though. Only a CD one. I don't have money for a new laptop either :/

Comment: @markmith, what happens if you boot up in command prompt?. Press F8 immediate after you power on your laptop > choose "Safe mode with Command Prompt" > Login with your details > on the Command prompt, type 'S'. Now see what happens?. If it is not working then it might be your hardware problem, else it should be your Operating system problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nothing happenz when I prezz F8

Comment: Why the hell waz my queztion marked az unclear? How can I fix the problem now? Nobody helped me!!